# Page Fails to Scroll

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile, cordova

From time to time, my app will stop allowing scrolling of the entire page length. It will work perfectly, for some time, then suddenly the page will stop scrolling and you can only view/use the section currently in the view-able area.

It is intermittent enough, that it is hard to track down, and diagnose.

I have had reports of this issue on both Android and iPhone/iPad products.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue? Where you able to find out the problem?

I am using PhoneGap/Cordova 2.2.0 with custom JavaScript.

Thank you.

-- Eric

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before when setting my body/html to 100% height in the css. The following is how I fixed it.

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```